# problem in updating a row in database using mysqli

Tags: php, sql

there is table named Book and this code is supposed to find a specific record and edit it's num to num-1, but it only edit num to -1.

```
$sql = 'SELECT num FROM Book
    WHERE bid="'.$_SESSION["sails bid{$i}"].'"';
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $numbers=(int)$row['num']-1;
    $sql='UPDATE Book
    SET num="'.$numbers.'"
    WHERE bid="'.$_SESSION["sails bid{$i}"].'"';
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you've overcomplicating this.  You don't need to select into PHP, perform the math, and then update.  Simple arithmetic can be performed in SQL.  For example:

```
UPDATE Book SET num = num - 1 WHERE bid = ?
```

Just bind your `bid` value (preferably [using query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of the string concatenation you're currently using) and you only need to execute that one `UPDATE` instead of all the code you have now.